# Load a JP2 image in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I was trying to upload a JP2 image into my GeoServer (version 2.19.1). I downloaded the [geoserver-2.19-RC-jp2k-plugin](https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_geoserver/downloads/GeoServer/2.19-RC/extensions/geoserver-2.19-RC-jp2k-plugin.zip/) and I placed the 4 jars (gt-jp2k-23.4.jar | imageio-ext-imagereadmt-1.3.2.jar | imageio-ext-kakadu-1.3.2.jar | imageio-ext-kakadujni-5.2.6.jar) in geoserver\WEB-INF\lib folder inside Tomcat.
Then, goining in GeoServer web panel, clicking on "Store", "Add new Store", "JP2K (Direct)", "Connection Parameters -> URL "file:C:\image.JP2" **I got this error**:

```
Failed to create reader from file:C:\myImage.JP2 and hints Hints: FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@37942677 REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@2316b249 COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@62ba68e7[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true
```

[image]

Comment: did you install the JP2K extension? https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/jp2k/index.html

Comment: @IanTurton thank you for the suggestion... Unfortunately I'm having trouble activating the plugin. If you are sure this is the solution to the problem, feel free to write it down as an answer.

Comment: [edit] your question to explain how you are installing it and what the issue is? TBH I would convert it to a GeoTiff and be done with it

Comment: @IanTurton edited! Thank you!

Comment: why would you add a 2.17.4 extension to a 2.19.1 GeoServer? the version numbers **must** match

Comment: @IanTurton same error with the 2.19 version

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.